# EnvDTE VS 2012 ProjectItems.AddFolder

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vsx, envdte

I am recreating an AddIn project that I had in VS 2010 and a basic function like adding a folder to the project is not working.
Giving me:

```
The kind 'vsProjectItemKindPhysicalFolder' passed to ProjectItems.AddFolder is invalid.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe this kind of folders are invalid for specif projects? Did you try `vsProjectItemKindVirtualFolder`? What is you project type?

Comment: The folder kind is optional, have you tried to omit it? Otherwise, what type of project are you targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to pass in the constant named `vsProjectItemKindPhysicalFolder` and not the name of the constant as a project type:

```
proj.ProjectItems.AddFolder(@"Generated", EnvDTE.Constants.vsProjectItemKindPhysicalFolder);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you already have a folder by that exact name on the physical disk, but is not part of the project yet. You should try renaming the existing folder and try doing that action again.